# Styling different groups in SAS SGPLOT

Tags: sas

I am trying to produce a graph with multiple groupings. The sample data code is:

> ```
> proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars;
>   by DriveTrain;
>   where n(Cylinders);
> run;
> ```

I used `dattrmap` to add distinct colors to the different groups as follow:

> ```
>   data MyAttrMap;
>    length MARKERCOLOR CONTRASTCOLOR color $25;
>    ID='myreg'; value='All' ; MARKERCOLOR='red'; color='red'; MARKERSYMBOL = 'circle'; output;
>    ID='myreg'; value='Front'; MARKERCOLOR='blue'; color='blue'; MARKERSYMBOL = 'circle'; output;
>    ID='myreg1'; value='USA'; CONTRASTCOLOR='yellow'; color='yellow'; output;
>    ID='myreg1'; value='Europe'; CONTRASTCOLOR='black'; color='black'; output;
>    ID='myreg1'; value='Asia'; CONTRASTCOLOR='green'; color='green'; >       >       output;
>   run;
>
>   proc sgplot data=work.cars
>    dattrmap=MyAttrMap;
>    hbarparm category=enginesize response=horsepower/group=DriveTrain barwidth=.5 attrid=myreg name='dt';
>   scatter X=MPG_City Y=enginesize /group=origin name='origin' attrid=myreg1;
>    keylegend 'dt' / title='Drive Train' location=outside position=bottom;
>   keylegend 'origin' / title='Origin' location=outside position=bottom;
>   where DriveTrain in ('All' 'Front');
>   run;
> ```

The Attrmap was created with the intention of having different colors for `Origin` and `DriveTrain` however, when the output is created the same colors applied to Origin are applied to DriveTrain.

I also tried using Proc template to change the style as follow:

> ```
>   /*Different colors from the ones used above*/
>   proc template;
>    define style MyStyle;
>   parent = Styles.Listing;
>    STYLE graphdata1 /
>                 MARKERSYMBOL = 'circle'
>                  LINESTYLE = 1
>                  CONTRASTCOLOR = liypk
>                  COLOR = red
>           ;
>           STYLE graphdata2 /
>                 MARKERSYMBOL = 'circle'
>                  LINESTYLE = 1
>                  CONTRASTCOLOR = stybr
>                  COLOR = yellow
>           ;
>           STYLE graphdata3 /
>                 MARKERSYMBOL = 'circle'
>                  LINESTYLE = 1
>                CONTRASTCOLOR = mog
>                 COLOR = green
>          ;
>           STYLE graphdata4 /
>                 MARKERSYMBOL = 'circle'
>                 LINESTYLE = 1
>                 CONTRASTCOLOR = brown
>                 COLOR = pink
>          ;
>           STYLE graphdata5 /
>                 MARKERSYMBOL = 'circle'
>                 LINESTYLE = 1
>                 CONTRASTCOLOR = black
>                  COLOR = grey
>           ;
>    end;
>   run;
> ```

But still the same results were obtained. Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to get this to work? I'm using SAS 9.3.

Another issue I'm encountering is the sorting. I want to sort the bars so that the same origins appear together and by the horsepower. I sorted using `sortkey=national` and used `grouporder=data` as recommended by SAS but this didn't change the ordering in the output. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Here is the output].

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about the `SORT`, `where n(DriveTrain)` logs an error.  Is that a typo ?

Comment: Fixed it, that was an error. Thanks.

Comment: Why are DriveTrain values labeled 'Horse Power' in your image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your attribute map data set. Because you haven't specified the lengths for the **Value** and **ID** column they're truncated and don't match your data so they don't get assigned correctly.

Simplifying your problem, I assigned all the elements for testing:

I also assumed this was mocked up because of the errors in the log.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars;
    by DriveTrain;
    where n(Cylinders);
run;

data MyAttrMap;
    length ID $10. linecolor MARKERCOLOR CONTRASTCOLOR fillcolor color value $25;
    ID='myreg1';
    value='USA';
    contrastcolor='cxaf8dc3';
    LINECOLOR='cxaf8dc3';
    MARKERCOLOR='cxaf8dc3';
    fillcolor='cxaf8dc3';
    output;
    ID='myreg1';
    value='Europe';
    contrastcolor='cx7fbf7b';
    LINECOLOR='cx7fbf7b';
    MARKERCOLOR='cx7fbf7b';
    fillcolor='cx7fbf7b';
    output;
    ID='myreg1';
    value='Asia';
    contrastcolor='cx91bfdb';
    LINECOLOR='cxfc8d59';
    MARKERCOLOR='cxfc8d59';
    fillcolor='cxfc8d59';
    output;
run;

ods graphics / attrpriority=none;

proc sgplot data=work.cars dattrmap=MyAttrMap;
    scatter X=MPG_City Y=enginesize /group=origin name='origin' attrid=myreg1;
    where DriveTrain in ('All' 'Front');
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although your modification doesn't include the two groups which is the main focus of this graph, your pointing out the truncation of variable lengths helped me in eventually fixing the problem and for this reason I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might find `SGPANEL` a better option for visually presenting the distributions of different groups.

```
ods html style=normal;
ods graphics / height=900px;

proc sgpanel data=sashelp.cars;
  panelby origin 
  / columns=3
  ;

  hbar enginesize 
  / group=drivetrain
    groupdisplay=cluster
  ;

  where 
    DriveTrain in ('Front', 'All')
    and not missing(cylinders)
  ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but I know when to use SGPANEL and this specific graph doesn't require it. The graph requires all groups to be plotted on the same panel.